# coredata error Make tableView can't be showed (NSFetchResultsController)

Tags: xcode, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

```
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of 

NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  
The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (1) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (0), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted). with userInfo (null)
```

the error like that? how can I know? what's wrong with my code.. I don't understand with that error.. anyone can tell me what is that? and how can I fix that hell?

number of section is always 1.. Why it start of 0 before the update? How do I make the table recoqnize that there is 1 and only 1 section before any updating?

```
    -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        return [[self.FetchController sections] count];
    }

    -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.FetchController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
        /*int numberOfRow=[sectionInfo numberOfObjects]-(self.numberOf20SkipFromtheBeginning*20);
        numberOfRow = MIN(20,numberOfRow);*/
        //int numberOfRow=MIN(100,[sectionInfo numberOfObjects]);
        CalledRowCountingNotYetCallRowForSection=true;
        [self.tableViewA setBounces:YES];

        if([sectionInfo numberOfObjects]>100){
            //[Timer searchCriteriaChanged];
            CLog(@"Something Wrong This NumberOfRow: %d", [sectionInfo numberOfObjects]);
        }


        return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    }

    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        DLog(@"Function TableView AT listnewController");

        CalledRowCountingNotYetCallRowForSection =false;
        if ([self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]==0)
        {
            DLog(@"Something is VERY WRONG. Number of Section: %d" ,indexPath.section);
        }
        DLog(@"Indexpath at cellForRowAtIndexPath : %d", indexPath);
        Business * theBiz=[self.FetchController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        return theBiz.CustomCell;

    }

    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        DLog(@"Function didselectrowatindexpath listnewcontroller");
        //[BNUtilitiesQuick UtilitiesQuick].currentBusiness=[[self.FetchController fetchedObjects] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]+self.numberOf20SkipFromtheBeginning*20];
        [BNUtilitiesQuick UtilitiesQuick].currentBusiness=[[self.FetchController fetchedObjects] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        [BNUtilitiesQuick SafelyPushControllerAtNavigationController:[BNUtilitiesQuick NearbyIsiKota].mDetailBusiness atNavigationController:[BNUtilitiesQuick NearbyIsiKota].navigationController];
    }

    - (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    DLog(@"controllerWillChangeContent: %@", controller);
    [self.tableViewA beginUpdates];

}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

    DLog(@"didChangeSection: %@", controller);

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableViewA insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableViewA deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    DLog(@"controller:%@\ndidChangeObject:%@\natIndexPath:%@\nforChangeType:%d\nnewIndexPath:%@\n",controller, anObject, indexPath, type, newIndexPath);

    UITableView *tableView = self.tableViewA;
    DLog(@"%@", self.tableViewA);
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
                [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:

            //[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
            //[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
            //[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
            break;
    }

}


- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableViewA endUpdates];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely caused by providing a `sectionNameKeyPath` for the NSFetchedResultsController when it doesn't need one.

If you provide a `sectionNameKeyPath` but there are no values yet for that key path, the fetched results controller will report that the table has zero sections. If that key path acquires a value, the fetched result controller will report that the table now has one or more sections.

To fix, make sure that `sectionNameKeyPath` is empty when you initialize the fetched results controller. You can also hardwire `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` to always return zero or one.